# Routify - what directory to place components that are not intended as routes?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component, routify

Basic question here.

In Routify, anything in the top level of the pages directory is rendered with an endpoint that matches the page name.

Ok - got it!

However, if I want to create a component that is not intended as an endpoint and is only intended to be imported into another page that *is* a route, what directory structure do I use?

More generally, what do I need to know to do this? Best practices ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would simply place them in a directory adjacent to `pages` and then you do something like `import MyComponent from '../../components/MyComponent.svelte` (with the correct number of ..)

```
- src
   - components
   - pages
```

As a bonus, if you call the folder `node_modules` instead like this

```
- src
   - node_modules
   - pages
```

you can just do `import Mycomponent from 'MyComponent.svelte'` but this is a way that not everyone likes.

Answer (score 2):

Components and folders prefixed with an underscore [are ignored by Routify](https://routify.dev/guide/introduction/structure) when it creates the routes for your app.

So, you could call your component `_MyComponent.svelte` and keep it in the same directory, or have a `_components` subdirectory and keep it there, named however you wish.